# Combobox filtering for listbox output is not working as expected

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I have a few controls (Combobox's I call DDL's) that I use as filters for a dynamic query, shown below.

I have a region, division filter - and BCI/BCV/ABC/etc dropdowns.

**When I select the region and division, the output list box correctly filters out everything except THOSE region/divisions.**  Good.

The problem comes in when I use the other DDL's, ABD/BCI/etc... those do not filter out correctly and I think it is with my and/or clauses below.

Can anyone see anything glaring or point me in the right direction to get this so that every control and ddl element filters out the data it is intended for - while keeping it in a format where the SQL itself is part of a string, like in my example?

```
Private Sub goBtn_Click()
          strSQL = "SELECT [account_number], [BCI_Amt], [BCV_Amt],[ABC_Amt], [other_Amt], " & _
        "[BCI_Amt]+[BCV_Amt]+[ABC_Amt]+[other_MRC_Amt], Division_Name, Region_Name, " & _
        "Tier, Unit_ID, Name, Description_2 " & _
        "FROM dbo_ndw_bc_subs " & _
        "WHERE DivisionDDL = [Division_Name] and RegionDDL = [Region_Name] " & _
        " and ( [BCI_Ind] = CheckBCI.value or [BCV_Ind] = CheckBCV.value or [ABC_Ind] = CheckABC.value " & _
        " or BCIServiceDDL = [Tier]" & _
        " or BCVServiceDDL = [Description_2]" & _
        " or ABCServiceDDL = [Unit_ID]  )" & _
        "ORDER BY 6 asc"
    Me.output1.RowSource = strSQL
    End Sub
```

One of the combo box DDL control codes.  There are check boxes that make the combo box visible or not visible.

```
Private Sub CheckBCV_Click()
  If Me.CheckBCV = vbTrue Then 
     Me.BCVServiceDDL.Visible = True
     Me.BCVServiceDDL = "Select:"
     strSQL = "SELECT  Distinct subs.[Description_2] FROM dbo_ndw_bc_subs "
     Me.BCVServiceDDL.RowSource = strSQL
     Me.BCVServiceDDL.Requery
  Else
     Me.BCVServiceDDL.Visible = False
     Me.BCVServiceDDL = ""
  End If
End Sub
```

Edit:  Added additional code to the first code block for context, and updated some comments.

To reiterate the point of my question - Since some of the DDL's work as expected while the others do not.  Is it in the AND/OR section where I have a problem - or am I forced to do an IF/IIF statement in the select.  (And if I do this IF solution - how would that be incorporated into a string the way I have it now, I have not seen an example of this in my research on a resolution).

Comment: This is a hard question to figure out what you're asking. Can you supply a better picture of your form and checkboxes and comboboxes? And maybe the difference between what you call working and not working - examples of right and wrong. These are basic to asking a good question

Comment: Concatenate references to form controls, don't include within quote marks. What should happen if no selection made in combobox? I recommend you build the SQL statement with conditional statements. Review http://allenbrowne.com/ser-62.html

Comment: There appear to be a few missing pieces to this puzzle still. Perhaps a data example and desired result (as @dbmitch mentioned) would shed some light on things.

Comment: Providing sample data would be a problem from works point of view, aside from it being 100+ columns wide and 34m rows.    I will try to reiterate the goal:  Region DDL, Division DDL, product/service/other DDL's exist.  When I pick North Division, Central Region, BCV = checked, BCI = checked --- I want the results to only show me records that match the North Division, Central Region, BCV true, BCI true results - and not 'all' results.    Currently, as is, the code will show me and filter the correct region and division, giving me North Central, but the products and service DDL's are not working

Comment: I've noticed that in SQL Server Mgmt Studio, that the SQL for this does work correctly - but it does not behave the same in Access.  The WHERE [BCI_Ind] = 1 returns content in SQL as expected, but does not filter the listbox in Access, with this --> "WHERE [BCI_Ind] = 1 " & _

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your top code sample should read more like this:

```
Private Sub goBtn_Click()
    Dim strSQL As String
    Dim strWhere As String 
    Dim strOp As String 

    strSQL = "SELECT [account_number], [BCI_Amt], [BCV_Amt],[ABC_Amt], [other_Amt], " & _
        "[BCI_Amt]+[BCV_Amt]+[ABC_Amt]+[other_MRC_Amt], Division_Name, Region_Name, " & _
        "Tier, Unit_ID, Name, Description_2 " & _
        "FROM dbo_ndw_bc_subs "

    strWhere = ""
    strOp = ""
    If Not IsNull(Me.DivisionDDL.Value) Then 
        strWhere = strWhere & strOp & "(Division_Name = """ & Me.DivisionDDL.Value & """)"
        strOp = " And "
    End If
    If Not IsNull(Me.RegionDDL.Value) Then 
        strWhere = strWhere & strOp & "(Region_Name = """ & Me.RegionDDL.Value & """)"
        strOp = " And "
    End If
    If Me.CheckBCI.Value Then 
        strWhere = strWhere & strOp & "(Tier = """ & Me.BCIServiceDDL.Value & """)"
        strOp = " And "
    End If
    If Me.CheckBCV.Value Then 
        strWhere = strWhere & strOp & "(Description_2 = """ & Me.BCVServiceDDL.Value & """)"
        strOp = " And "
    End If
    If Me.CheckABC.Value Then 
        strWhere = strWhere & strOp & "(Unit_ID = """ & Me.ABCServiceDDL.Value & """)"
        strOp = " And "
    End If

    If Len(strWhere) > 0 then 
        strSQL = strSQL & " WHERE " & strWhere
    End If
    strSQL = strSQL & " ORDER BY 6 asc"

    Me.output1.RowSource = strSQL

End Sub
```

This is wordier, but much closer to correct. P.S. I guessed that all values are strings. If not remove the quoting around non-string values.

Comment: This works amazingly well, thank you for your time and input.  I've swapped out the logic to yours and am expanding upon it now.  I have marked yours as an answer because it hits the exact problem I was having with updating my listbox correctly.